# How can I change an link's image when it's tabbed to?

Tags: css, css-selectors

We are writing a site for a user cannot use a mouse. He wants to press Tab on the keyboard to move between images and press return to go to the href link associated with that image. We got that much worked out OK.

But how can we highlight the image in some way so he can easily see which image he has tabbed to?

We don't have an jQuery skills so we are trying to keep our coding to html and css

We have the code:

I thought I could introduce a class to change something about the image.
For example, we introduced a class
  .classA {border:double;}
and using it
     
But that didn't work. We tried lots of effects but none of them worked.

Any suggestions as to how we can highlight the image he has tabbed to?

Comment: `img:focus { border:1px solid red; }` ? Not entirely sure if images can be tabbed to without a wrapping anchor though.. in which case you'd want `a:focus img` as your selector

Answer (score 0):

> how we can highlight the image he has tabbed to

When tabbing between anchors on a page, that element gains "focus" - using the `:focus` pseudo selector, we can therefore restyle images that are inside an anchor that has been tabbed to with `a:focus img` - for example:

```
a:focus img {
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

Though adding a border could break layouts - you could instead do something like:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #F00;
```

To give it a red glow - making it obvious, without affecting the layout of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that by default, the browser puts on an outline.

Try:

> img:focus {
>     outline:none; 
>     border:2px solid #ABCDEF;
>   }